# Ignore evaluation of '\n' character in sys.argv

Tags: python, sys

Oddly enough, when running this program with the arguments of

```
program.py "(lp0\nS'cat'\np1\naI5\na."
```

With program.py being:

```
import sys,pickle
print sys.argv[1]=="(lp0\nS'cat'\np1\naI5\na."
```

False is printed... I have narrowed the difference in evaluation to the \n character however I can find no way of ignoring such.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Double the backslashes in your check.

Comment: Python interprets '\n' as a newline character. If you want to place the two characters '\' and 'n' in a string you need to write '\\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *raw string literal* like this:

```
sys.argv[1] == r"(lp0\nS'cat'\np1\naI5\na."
```

Also, you can use a string in the parameters without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the syntax of strings in Python and in the shell (presumably Bash) is different.

You may want to run the program as

```
echo       $'"(lp0\nS\'cat\'\np1\naI5\na.'
program.py $'"(lp0\nS\'cat\'\np1\naI5\na.'
```